# AngularJS Valid Activation

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm currently developing an [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) activation form which allows the user to activate their account before being able to use the additional features, which happens to be another form.

**What I'm trying to achieve:**
User enters Membership and Activation Number. If these numbers are valid *(within the JSON data)* the user is granted access. if not, an error message will be displayed

**Current Problem:**
I've managed to check if the Membership Number is valid and return a message to validate but am unable to check both the Membership and Activation Numbers together.

I'm developing this project on Plnkr, please feel free to assist and point me in the right direct. Thank you.

http://plnkr.co/edit/5uPSn2ae0yFjYzujPFWm?p=preview

**Controller.JS**

```
var formCtrl = angular.module('formCtrl', []);

formCtrl.controller('activation', function($scope){
  $scope.myData = {
    "membershipNumber": {
        "5464565": [
            {
                "activationNumber": "5464565X"
            }
        ],
        "54645651": [
            {
                "activationNumber": "54645651X"
            }
        ],
        "45165": [
            {
                "activationNumber": "45165X"
            }
        ],
        "4692": [
            {
                "activationNumber": "4692X"
            }
        ],
        "541": [
            {
                "activationNumber": "541X"
            }
        ],
        "D4554160N": [
            {
                "activationNumber": "D4554160NX"
            }
        ]
    }
  };
  $scope.results = []; 

  $scope.findValue = function(membershipValue) {     
    angular.forEach($scope.myData.membershipNumber, function(value, key) {
      if (key === membershipValue) {
        $scope.results.push({membershipNumber: key, activationNumber: value[0].activationNumber});
      }
    });
  };
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I got exactly want yo wanted to achieve, but it might be that you're not actually using the scope content to check and should use that instead?

```
$scope.findValue = function() {     
    angular.forEach($scope.myData.membershipNumber, function(value, key) {
      if (key === $scope.membershipValue &&
          value[0].activationNumber === $scope.activationValue) {
        $scope.results.push({membershipNumber: key, activationNumber: value[0].activationNumber});
      }
    });
  };
```

See:
http://plnkr.co/edit/tqoEwZinCXKQho9tTxgp?p=preview

Sorry if this isn't what you meant.